# Error while running script with nohup

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I got this error while running my script with nohup sh:

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

My script is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
report_log="report.log";
grep -A 3 'successful\|ERROR COUNT EXCEEDED' *.log  > ${report_log};
echo ${report_log};
MAX_ERR_COUNT_EXCEED_MSG="No Max Count Error.";
if grep "ERROR COUNT EXCEEDED" ${report_log}; then
   MAX_ERR_COUNT_EXCEED_MSG="MAX ERROR COUNT EXCEEDED, CHECK RECORD COUNT!";
fi
RESULT_MSG="Execution successful";
if grep '\([1-9]\d*\b\)' ${report_log} | grep 'data errors'; then
   RESULT_MSG="Execution with ERROR";
fi
cat ${report_log} <(echo "-----------") <(echo "${MAX_ERR_COUNT_EXCEED_MSG}") <(echo "${RESULT_MSG}") | mailx -s "Test Result" abc@test.com
```

It is a script to filter through some log files and generate a reporting email on the execution status from those files.

The error seems to come from the usage of `<(` in the script, but having added the bash shebang i thought it should work. The script run without issue if running using the command below:

```
. ./script.sh
```

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "running my script with nohup sh"? Do you start it as `nohup sh /path/to/your/script.sh` or as `nohup /path/to/your/script.sh`? In the first case the shebang line is ignored because the interpreter is called explicitly.

Comment: Hi, i'm running it using `nohup sh /path/to/script`. In that case is there anyway i can overwrite the interpreter? This is because this script is called by another script and generally others run those scripts using `nohup sh`

Comment: when i try running it via `nohup /path/to/script` i get an error `nohup: cannot run command 'script.sh': No such file or directory` instead

Comment: So you cannot influence how the script is called. Can you modify the script?

Comment: have you tried `nohup bash /path/to/myscript.sh` ?

Comment: ah my bad..typo in the path for the no such file error. I will try and raise this issue.

Comment: Is the problem solved already? I was going to suggest a solution; don't need that?. Until now there's just an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that running the script as `nohup sh /path/to/your/script.sh` overrides the shebang line interpreter. When called as `sh` then `bash` turns off certain features (that is probably similar with other shells) and thus cannot parse process substitution any more.

The solution is to make sure that `bash` is running without restrictions. This can be done by checking for an environment variable and call the script again with `bash` (instead of `sh`):

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ "YES" = "$RUNNING_AS_BASH" ]; then
        eval 'cat <(echo "-----------")'
else
        test -f "$0" || exit 1
        RUNNING_AS_BASH="YES" exec bash "$0"
fi
```

Unfortunately `bash` as `sh` parses the whole `if` structure. Thus in order to avoid the error the incompatible syntax must be hidden in an eval statement.

This can be avoided if the `eval` action is taken out of the `if` structure because the rest of the script is not parsed:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ "YES" != "$RUNNING_AS_BASH" ]; then
        test -f "$0" || exit 1
        RUNNING_AS_BASH="YES" exec bash "$0"
fi

cat <(echo "-----------")
```